# Can't execute PHP via cron

Tags: php, ubuntu

My cron commands are "php -q PATH-TO-FILE"

I'm getting "/bin/sh: php: not found" errors.  What path should I be using to execute PHP, or how can I find out?

**update**

PHP5-cli is now installed.  Now I'm getting `/bin/sh: /var/lib/php5: Permission denied` when all of these are run as root

Comment: Have you installed your distro's equivalent of `php-cli`?  You may not have a command-line PHP interpreter. Should be something like `sudo apt-get install php5-cli` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @jscott if that was the case the error would be `command not found` and not that `/bin/sh has not found the php file to execute`

Comment: jScott that was it, it wasn't installed.  Didn't realize it came seperately!

Comment: Could you provide the crontab entry? And perhaps the source of the PHP file you're trying to exec? The message you post sounds like you're trying to walk/search the `/var` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line interpreter of PHP can be a separate package.  I know it is in Debian.  On Ubuntu the following command should install the requisite tools:

`sudo apt-get install php5-cli`

Answer (score 10):

Because your crontab does now know what the ENVIROMENT is so you must tell the PHP path.

```
/usr/bin/php -q PATH-TO-FILE
```

If the file is not on the above path which is the most common path in most default installation you can run the bellow command to find where it is:

```
whereis php
```

Comment: to find out the path of php on your server you can type whereis php. but it is most likely /usr/bin/php just like Prix suggested.

Comment: @egorgry true... i will edit with it but just in case the user does not have a default installation so he is aware of how to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the error like this

```
/bin/sh: 1: usr/bin/php: not found
```

I was missing the '/'
I made the changes like this

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/admin/cron.php
```

Now it is working. The path should be correct